# How to prevent against XSS located in Javascript HREF attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, xss

```
<a href='javascript:do_something("<?php echo $untrusted_input; ?>");'>Test</a>
<script>
    function do_something(str) {
        //...
    }
</script>
```

I am wondering how to encode the variable `$untrusted_input` (for instance in PHP) in order to avoid XSS (javascript injections) being executed?

In this case, the `htmlspecialchars` function is insecure because it replaces the injected `"` with `&quot;`, but the HTML parser will still interpret the `&quot;` as a valid `"`:

If you try this code, you will see that the alert is displayed:

```
<a href='javascript:do_something("&quot;+alert(&quot;injected&quot;)+&quot;");'>Test 4</a>
<script>
    function do_something(str) {
        //...
    }
</script>
```

And the `addslashes` function is also insecure because it adds slashes before `'` and `"` but does not encode `&quot;`, so it is possible to escape using the example above.

Please note that I am asking this question as a cyber-security researcher and I would like to know the way we could easily remediate this problem ? As a developer, I never do this way.

Thanks,

Comment: 1) Get out of the previous century, and stop using `href='javascript:…'`. 2) Separate data and code. For example by placing the actual data into a custom data attribute, and then reading it from there in your Javacript code.

Comment: `json_encode` does a pretty good job, provided you use it with the appropriate options.

Comment: `json_encode("&quot;", JSON_HEX_AMP)`

Comment: You could still combine it with an additional layer, that replaces `%` with `%25`, to “defuse” that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a meta-tag and set your content-security-policy to forbid inline javascript:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

See [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for further information.

Comment: But the way the question is currently phrased, the point of this is to keep `<a href='javascript:do_something(…)'>` working _per se_, and this will kill it completely.